# Python Flask - How to pass a python List Data elements into the Jquery "Lists": [{ [] }]

Tags: python, jquery

I'm trying to pass a Python List Result to a Jquery List.

Can someone help with the code to include jinja templates into Jquery to iterate the List values ?

**Python Flask Code:-**

```
@app.route('/mapcolumns_link',methods =['GET','POST'])
def mapcolumns_link():
    val1 = request.form.getlist('duallistbox')
    val2 = request.form.getlist('duallistbox2')
    return render_template('mapcolumns_link.html', titlepage = 'MapColumns',**val1=val1**, **val2=val2**)
```

**Val1 output:-**

```
['ACNT_NO', 'CLIENT_ID', 'CNTRY']
```

**Val2 output:-**

```
['STATUS', 'ACCNT_NO', 'CNTRY_CODE', 'CURRENCY_CODE']
```

*Please note the List values as shown above is not constant and it may have many values/change in runtime.*

**mapcolumns_link.html**

```
<script>
    var fieldLinks;
    var inputOri;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                inputOri = {
                    "localization": {
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "associationMode": "oneToOne", // oneToOne,manyToMany
                        "lineStyle": "square-ends",
                        "buttonErase": "Erase Links",
                        "displayMode": "original",
                        "whiteSpace": $("input[name='whiteSpace']:checked").val(), //normal,nowrap,pre,pre-wrap,pre-line,break-spaces default => nowrap
                        "mobileClickIt": false
                    },
                    "Lists": [
                        {
                            "name": "Columns in File1",
                            "list": [

                                        {{ val1|safe }}
                                //"firstName",
                                //"lastName",
                                //"City"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Columns in File2",
                            "list": [
                            {{ val2|safe }}
                                //"first_name",
                                //"last_name",
                                //"email_adress",
                                //"Phone number",
                            ],
                        }
                    ],
                    "existingLinks": [{ "from": "lastName", "to": "last_name" }, { "from": "firstName", "to": "first_name" }, { "from": "role", "to": "jobTitle" }]
                };


            $(".fieldLinkerSave").on("click",function(){
                var results = fieldLinks.fieldsLinker("getLinks");
                $("#output").html("output => " + JSON.stringify(results));
            });


          fieldLinks=$("#original").fieldsLinker("init",inputOri);

        });

     </script>
```

**Desired Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
{% for item in val1 %}
    {{ item|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

In the Jinja docu you can find some more examples.
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

Happy Coding, T

Comment: Have tried this logic and it didn't work... "Lists": [
      {
       "name": "Columns in File1",
       "list": [

       {% for item in val1 %}
                                {{ item|safe }}
                            {% endfor %}

       ]
      }